# Logical not operator on pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Code:

```
struct person *p = NULL;
printf("%d, %d\n", !p, !!p);
```

In above code, the `!` operator works on pointer, I know `!` works with `int`, but what happens when it works with `pointer`?

Is pointer treated as `int` in nature, or the `!` do a type convert?

---

I found the c99 reference mentioned in answer here:
[www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `c99` standard, chapter 6.5.3.3, paragraph 1

> The operand of the unary + or - operator shall have arithmetic type; of the ~ operator,
>   integer type; of the ! operator, scalar type.

and , from 6.2.5, paragraph 21,

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types.

So, one can use the `pointer` type directly with the unary `!` operator. The `!` is evaluated normally.

<sup>Maybe worthy to mention, in case of `pointer` usage, `NULL` value is a *False* any value other than `NULL` is considered *True*.</sup>

Comment: Good answer, by the way I checked the c99 doc and found that the chp should be `6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators`

Answer (score 1):

Whatever, the pointer is just an address of something, i.e. an Number. So '!' operator would play as usual with the pointer too.

Comment: In this case you're right that `!ptr` for some pointer type `ptr` is valid and equivalent to `ptr == NULL`. But I feel it's very important to note that according to the C standard pointers are explicitly not a numerical type